# jQuery pager with static height and dynamic content

Tags: jquery, dynamic, pager

I have page that needs to take user content from a CMS and display on a page that has a static height with the overflow broken into pages on the front end.

I've looked into a variety of jQuery Pager plugins and they all require a specific tag to target (p, div, li) where in my case I will not know what tag the user enters into the CMS.

```
var content = $("#weekly-features").children();
var pageHeight = 0;
var nextHeight = 0;
var pageCount = 0;
var start = 0;

    // loop through and wrap p's with page divs
for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {

        pageHeight += $(content[i]).outerHeight();

        if ((i + 1) < content.length) {
nextHeight = $(content[i + 1]).outerHeight();
}

        if ((pageHeight + nextHeight) >= 400) {
pageCount++;
$(content.slice(start, i)).wrapAll('<div class="page' + pageCount + '" />');
pageHeight = 0;
start = i;
}
}

    // wrap remaining page
if (start < content.length) {
pageCount++;
$(content.slice(start)).wrapAll('<div class="page' + pageCount + '" />');
}

    // show first page
$("#weekly-features div").each(function() {
if ($(this).attr('class') == "page1") { return; }
else { $(this).hide(); }
});

    buildPagerNav(pageCount);
}
```

Any ideas?

- Edit to be more specific- the problem is with the static height requirement: my html looks something like this:

paragraph 1 (short)

paragraph 2 (short)

paragraph 3 (long)

- list 1
- list 2
- list 3
- list 4
- list 5

paragraph 4 (short)

- list 1
- list 2
- list 3
- list 4
- list 5

where the short paragraphs will be on the same page and long list will need to be broken into separate pages... Kind of like inserting a dynamic page break in Word I guess..

Comment: what pager plugin you are using?

Comment: I tried out a few including: http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/pager/ but I couldn't find one that would break up pages by a static height requirement. The above code is my attempt at rolling my own- as you can see I am not a JS ninja :)

Comment: so your code has error or it does not run at all? if it has error, what kind of of error ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you consider using $("*") selector ? That will select any tag avaiable

to be precise, you could do something like this

$("#contentCMS *").pager();

OR

$("#contentCMS").find(*).pager();

Comment: That's pretty much the same as doing $("#weekly-features").children(); right?

Comment: No, * selector not the same as children() method. * will select all children and grandchildren of target element, while children only selects the children of target element.